# Deployed two dependent contracts: BigNumber Error: new BigNumber() not a base 16 number

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Parent:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

import "./Config.sol";

contract ParentContract{

    ConfigContract _config;

    constructor(ConfigContract config) public{
        _config = ConfigContract(config);
    }

    function getNameFromOtherContract() public view returns(string) {
        return _config.getName();
    }
}
```

Config:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract ConfigContract{

    constructor() public{
    }

    function getName() external pure returns (string) {
        return "Amel";
    }
}
```

deploy script:

```
const Parent = artifacts.require("./ParentContract");
const Config = artifacts.require("./ConfigContract");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(Config)
    .then(() => Config.deployed())
    .then(config => deployer.deploy(Parent, config.address));
};
```

Deployment is successful, but problem is that when I call:

> truffle(ourTestNet)> parent.getNameFromOtherContract()

I get:

```
BigNumber Error: new BigNumber() not a base 16 number:
```

Comment: which version of truffle are you using? to me it work file truffle(development)> parent.getNameFromOtherContract() => 'Amel' .

Comment: Truffle v4.1.8 (core: 4.1.8)
Solidity v0.4.23 (solc-js)

Comment: Also when I try to load contract from address in remix I get only getName to execute from ConfigContract, and nothing else. Like ParentContract is not at that address at all.

Comment: hm i used ganache instead of geth, and it works.. not sure what's the issue.